# RabbitMQ mirroring is possible when an anonymous(randomly named) queue is created?

Tags: rabbitmq, mirroring

I've made several policies for policy making test. And it worked well.
What if I'm making a randomly named queue and want to make it mirrored?

Comment: I've been searching the documentation for several hours now. I don't see any information on how to mirror a "server-named" queue without using the deprecated classic queue mirroring. When I try to create a quorum queue with an empty queue name, I get the error: "PRECONDITION_FAILED - Cannot declare a server-named queue for type rabbit_quorum_queue". I found this link, but it does not provide an adequate explanation or alternative: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/2296. My use case is to implement RPC in a high availability cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Completely" randomly named, hardly... You could prepend a word to it or something, and do "begging with" pattern in the policy for example. Search for *Some examples* in [this page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html).